# How to copy Shopify JavaScript Trigger to open and close the cart?

Tags: javascript, jquery

On this page: https://www.smokingjacket.london/product/buddhas-lips/ there is a red shopify cart icon that appears on the right hand side. When you click the cart icon it opens the tray and when you click it again it closes it. This website is built with Wordpress with Shopfiy buy now buttons on top.

I would like to have a link in my navigation bar that replicates this functionality. I have tried to use a JavaScript trigger that Shopify suggested but I do not think that the trigger is being used on the page.

I have also found a div class which I believe binds to the trigger but that does not seem to work either.

I would be enormously grateful if anyone could suggest some code that would allow an image / text to trigger the opening and closing of the cart.

Thank you

Shopify's own code

and

A div class

------------------------------------------Javascript Trigger that does not work-------

```
ShopifyEmbed.root.showCartContent()
```

------------------------------------------ Safety check to make sure Shopify code is on every page.-------

```
if(typeof ShopifyEmbed === 'object'){
if(typeof ShopifyEmbed.root === 'object'){
if(typeof ShopifyEmbed.root.showCartContent === 'function'){
  ShopifyEmbed.root.showCartContent();
}
```

}
}

------------------------------------------ Div Class-------

`shopify-buy__cart-toggle`

Expected result: Cart opens
Actual result: cart does not open